# Doxygen:Is there an option to checking spellings (spell check) in doxygen special comments

Tags: doxygen, pdflatex

I am using Doxygen to generate PDF files

Writing special doxygen comments inside .c and .h files I can able to run Doxygen on .c and .h files and parsing the special comments inside them and prepare .pdf file reports.

Most of the times I found many spelling mistakes in my PDF report. Hence I really need to checkout whether any Doxygen configuration option available for checking spelling mistakes and correct them.

Please help on this.

Thank you,
MMK

Comment: There are no settings for spelling checking in doxygen. For spell checking source code you need to use a separate package (like aspell, hunspell, codespell ...), search with e.g  google for "spell check source code", ask on the sister site software recommendations (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Had the same issue, but did not find a proper solution. @albert, spell checking on the entire source code raises too many issues with non doxygen comments, and the code itself ... so a way to integrate, somehow, doxygen with a spell checker will be a huge plus.

Comment: @MarcAlff You can generate e.g. the xml output (without source code `XML_PROGRAMLISTING`, though include files will probably still appear) and process this. Another way is to do a spellcheck and create a heuristic list with words to ignore (Like Fossies.org does). A further way is to generate a RTF file and do this with a spell checker of the word processor. A problem for doxygen would also be that a spell check should work for the languages doxygen supports. Though when of interest to you you can always try to implement it yourself and share the program).

Comment: When writing a next idea came, use the doxygen option `-d commentscan` and process the output with a spell checker.

Comment: Hi @albert. Actually, I tried to generate XML doc, use XSLT to extract only comments, and feed that to a spell checker. The main issue was, once with a mistake reported by the spell checker, how to correlate back to a FILE and LINE in the source code, to know where to fix the broken comment. Finding manually source comments from generated reports is tedious.

Comment: @MarcAlff Well when you have the offending word you could use a program like `grep` with line numbers and this should quite quickly indicate where the problem lies. It all would probably require some scripting.

Comment: @albert, not really, because this grep will again match plain code and non doxygen comments. Probably can be solved, my point was that this area needs better tooling. And thanks, -d commentscan is documented now (#8051)